# How do I install a .deb file that is actually a directory?

Tags: software-installation

I'm trying to install a printer driver ([from Epson](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule) if it matters) but when I try to unpack the `.tar.gz` file I'm getting a directory called `epsonscan2-bundle-6.6.42.0.x86_64.deb` instead of a file.

I tried just installing with `dpkg` or `apt` as per [How do I install a .deb file via the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40779/how-do-i-install-a-deb-file-via-the-command-line) however
`apt` reasonably responds `E: Read error - read (21: Is a directory)` -- `dpkg`'s objection is that the directory `is not a Debian format archive`

There are a dozen different questions about installing `.deb` files in general, but none that I can find that address a file that is actually a directory.

Comment: The file you want is probably inside the directory

Comment: @PonJar `apt` and `dpkg` definitely want a .deb file, which is the whole directory.

Comment: Have you looked inside the directory? There is probably a file with the same name as the directory

Comment: I have. There is not.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is really weird how Epson packs this driver.

It is really a directory, not a deb file. The directory contains other directories with real deb files and an `install.sh` script.

The script installs required dependencies and the debs.

Start `install.sh` script from that directory to install the driver.

So copy that `epsonscan2-bundle-6.6.42.0.x86_64.deb` to your Home and run:

```
cd epsonscan2-bundle-6.6.42.0.x86_64.deb
sudo ./install.sh
```

Comment: This offends me, just on principle. But I believe you.

Comment: As it turns out there are just two directories in here, `core` and `plugins` in addition to the `install.sh` script. And each of those includes an actual `.deb` file. So I'm going to try installing those directly.

Comment: @Amanda if you look through the `install.sh` script it just runs `dpkg --install` for the `.deb` files in the subdirectories.

Comment: `.x86_64.deb` is their platform ID (64-bit Debian-ish), it just happens to look a lot like the filename of a deb package.

Comment: Appending a filename extension (or something that looks alike) to a directory name is really confusing, shame on Epson who did this.